# A really weird problem - site works in FF3.0 not in FF3.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

[Can someone please look into this.](http://www.daftsquad.com/demo/)

Click on showcase, then on the logo it should open a modal window with the logo, everything works fine in FF 3.0 but in FF 3.5 the tab switches from showcase to home after clicking the logo.

But wait it is more weirder, if you observe, the first time you click on the thumbnail it instantly changes to home, but if you go back to showcase and then click on the thumbnail the second time it wont change until you click close.

This is driving me nuts, please help!

Comment: Works for me on Firefox 3.5.1 (specifically, Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.1) Gecko/20090715 Firefox/3.5.1).

Comment: Ah, hang on, it changes the large box back to "Home" when closing the "dialog", but not the navigation. I don't get the "first time" problem though.

Comment: Seems a problm with events. Do you use them a lot ? I mean, excepted onclick

Comment: Update to FF 3.5.1. It works well.

Comment: I am using FF 3.5.1 it doesn't work. Also just noticed it doesn't work in Opera too

Comment: disable all FF plugins, or make a clean install. something is wrong with your browser not your code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change some of your jQuery arround, I had a similar problem using jQuery inside of tabs. I was using the accordion plugin inside of a tab, you have to set it up to do this:

```
        $("#tabs").tabs(
        {
            load: function(ui)
            {
                var edata = $('#accordion');
                if(edata==undefined)
                {
                    if(edata[0].clientHeight > 0)
                    {
                        edata.accordion(
                        {
                            autoHeight: false
                        });
                    }
                }
            },
            show: function(ui)
            {
                if(edata==undefined)
                    {
                    var edata = $('#accordion');
                    edata.accordion(
                    {
                        autoHeight: true
                    });
                    $('#accordion').fadeTo(200,1);
                }
            }
        });
```

I also used an additional fade with mode code inside of the page being loaded by the tabs function, to prevent a FOUC (Flash of unstyled content).

That is all inside of the document ready function. From what I gathered it won't run right because it's trying to run the code before the content finishes loading, and the connection is "missed", causing it to kind of half-work only one time.